# Vue.js / Vuex + axios sends multiple PUT Request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, single-page-application, vuex

The user on my SPA is able to add/update and delete groups.

I've set up a Vuex store and an API helper module. In the EditGroup component, a method gets executed when the user press "save changes".

The issue is, axios sends 5 to 20 PUT requests but the method gets executed only once. On a GET, POST or DELETE request axios sends one request.

**In my EditGroup component:**

```
saveSelected : function () {
        this.$store.dispatch(ACTION_PUT_GROUP, {
            data : this.selected
        });
    },
```

**In my Vuex store:**

```
[actionTypes.ACTION_PUT_GROUP]({ commit }, payload) {
    api.methods.group.put(payload.data, commit, mutationTypes.EMPTY_MUTATION);
},
```

**In my API helper module:**

```
function _sendRequest(url, method, data, commit, commitHandler) {
    axios({
        method: method,
        data: data,
        url: url,
        responseType: "application/json"
    }).then(function (response) {
        commit(commitHandler, response.data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        _handle();
    });
}
// ...
export default {
    methods : {
        group : {
            // ...
            put: function (data, commit, commitHandler) {
                _sendRequest("api/group/" + data.Id, "put", data, commit, commitHandler);
            },
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot from Firefox:**
[image: Networklog from Firefox]

**Screenshot of the axios Error:**
[image: axios Error]

**Update 1 (15.10.2018)**

This is the code from my .NET Core Controller

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult PutGroup(string id, [FromBody] Group group)
    {
        if (id != group.Id)
            return BadRequest();

        // Validation ...
        context.CreateOrUpdateItem(group);
        // ...

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(GetGroup), "Group", new { id = id });
    }
```

Comment: Status 302 is a redirect. Is it a login issue?

Comment: @eric99 Nope, the request gets redirected to the GET-Endpoint

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**: Axios don't like to get redirected after a Put reqeust :)

**Solution (temp)**: Don't redirect...

**Solution**: I'll create an issue in the issue tracker of Axios on Github. >>> https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1829