# Axios - get data from api in vuex actions?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

How to correctly transfer or rewrite the function in actions that will receive the first photo from each album in?

my photos models:

```
import { api } from "@/apis/config";
const endPoint = 'photos'
const state = {
    photos: []
}
const getters = {}
const mutations = {
    SET_PHOTOS(state, data) {
        state.photos = data
    }
}
const actions = {
    loadMore(id) {
        api.get(`photos?albumId=${id}`).then(response => {
            return response.data[0].thumbnailUrl;
        });
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

And my album component:

```
...
<script>
import {mapActions} from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "GridAlbums",
  props: ['album'],
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      errored: false,
      photo: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.photo = this.loadMore(this.album.id)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("photos", ["loadMore"])
  }
}
</script>
...
```

Here is my configuration file for api, where VUE_APP_HOST is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_HOST,
})

api.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response
    },
    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)
```

If you get the data this way, then everything turns out as it should:
[image: Getting data from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com]

Comment: Please specify your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js / Vuex + axios sends multiple PUT Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609326/vue-js-vuex-axios-sends-multiple-put-request)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding async / await in vuex actions, because actions must be asynchronous and store and mutations synchronous.

Also use try / catch instead Promise that way you keep your code cleaner